# Как найти пропорцию размера в Picturebox?

Tags: c#

Есть `picturebox`. С помощью мыши я выбираю прямоугольник, который буду вырезать и сохранять в файл. Изображение большое, но вмещаю я его в picturebox  с помощью свойства Zoom. Понятное дело, что размеры в зуммированной и полной картинке будут отличаться. И картинка которая я вырежу не будет пропорционально реальным размерам.

```
 int mouseX, mouseY;
 private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            rec = new Rectangle(0, mouseY - 100, pictureBox1.Width, 250);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
        }
  private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseX = e.X;
            mouseY = e.Y;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

 private  Image Crop(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
        {
            cropArea.Width = img.Width;
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
            return bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Непонятно зачем вы рисуете изображение на `PictureBox`, если хотите использовать свойство `SizeMode = Zoom`. Для того чтобы оно работало нужно положить готовое изображение, `Bitmap` например, в свойство `Image`, на нарисованное вручную его действие не распространяется.
2. Пропорции можно узнать из размера, а размер из свойства `ClientSize` или `ClientRectangle`, как больше нравится.